# How to post a marker on Google Maps and have it so other users can see the marker?

Tags: android, google-maps

Does Google Maps already handle user interaction?

I'm able to post a marker onto my map activity but I can't test the app (I don't have another phone) to see if another 'user' can see the freshly posted marker. I feel like it's just private right now, so only the user who posts the marker can only see his/her marker.

Do I need to set up a Backend with Cloud Endpoints? If so, are there any answers on stackoverflow that could show me the DO's and DON'Ts ?

Comment: It's against SO policy to ask for off site resources or tutorials - I'd recommend you remove that last question to prevent it from getting flagged.

Comment: @ahoffner Okay, thanks. Is my edit more acceptable now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I have really understood your question, but I think you have two way.

You can create a map on google maps in [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) and link use this map (or link it)

or

your app had to ask your server for the position of the marker, so you have to implement a little web service that saves your marker position and calls it when your app put a marker on the map, and before loading the map you have to download the marker positions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry about the wording. I'm just not sure if Google Maps is set up so that if I post a marker on my app right now, another user can see it WITHOUT having to do any of the server side / connections behind it.

But yeah, I guess it seems like I have to use Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: No problem! just a reminder, if you haven't others devices maybe you can use virtual devices

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the emulator in Android Studio. Going to give that a shot. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, new Android Studio emulator is great, give it a chance! If my answer helps you, please mark it as "accepted".